# KendoUI for ASPMVC TreeView: display the Json response on behalf of the Tree

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display a tree of categories with remote data binding.
here is the Controller method:

```
    public JsonResult KendoTree(Guid? id)
    {
        var categoriesBO = _categoryManager.GetAllCategory().
            Where(c=> id==null ? c.ParentId==null : c.ParentId == id).
            Select(c=> new
            {
                id = c.Id,
                Name = c.Name,
                hasChildren = c.CategoryChilds.Any()
            });
        return Json(categoriesBO, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

here is the cshtml file

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "KendoTree";
}

    <h2>KendoTree</h2>

    @Html.Kendo().TreeView().Name("Categories").DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("KendoTree", "CategoryManagement")
    )).DataTextField("Name")
```

The browser display the Json result(an array) on behalf of the tree.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I got it: I have to have a Controller action that returns a view then call the kendo Html helper from inside the related view.